# Comma is breaking Grouping

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regular expression that's match anything as a parameter for this string `concat(1st,2nd)` and extract three matching groups as below :

**Group1**: concat

**Group2**: 1st

**Group3**: 2nd.

I have tried this :`^\s*(concat)\(\s*(.*?)\s*\,\s*(.*)\)\s*$`, and it worked fine until I had a parameter with comma as below:

`concat(regex(3,4),regex(3,4))`. It seams the comma is breaking it down, how to ignore the parameter content and take it as a seperate group?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/MXCxlJ/1

Comment: This is working fine, please could you show how to use it in C# as a string match?

Comment: Yes, the pattern at https://regex101.com/r/MXCxlJ/1 is a PCRE pattern. .NET is quite different when it comes to recursion (actually, .NET regex does not support recursion, it supports balanced constructs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\s*(concat)\(\s*((?>\w*\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)|\w+))\s*,\s*((?>\w*\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)|\w+))\)\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cs*%28concat%29%5C%28%5Cs*%28%28%3F%3E%5Cw*%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%7C%5Cw%2B%29%29%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*%28%28%3F%3E%5Cw*%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%7C%5Cw%2B%29%29%5C%29%5Cs*%24&i=concat%281st%2C2nd%29%0D%0Aconcat%28regex%283%2C4%29%2Cregex%283%2C4%29%29&o=m).

**Details**

- `^` -  start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(concat)` - Group 1: `concat` word
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `({arg})` - Group 2: `arg` pattern:

  - `\w*` - 0+ word chars
  - `\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)` - `(`, then any amount of nested parentheses or chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`
  - `|\w+` - or just 1+ word chars
- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `({arg})` - Group 3: `arg` pattern
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/e7NYeG):

```
var arg = @"(?>\w*\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)|\w+)";
var pattern = $@"^\s*(concat)\(\s*({arg})\s*,\s*({arg})\)\s*$";
var match = Regex.Match("concat(regex(3,4),regex(3,4))", pattern);
if (match.Success) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3].Value);
}
// => concat     regex(3,4)    regex(3,4)
```

Results:

[image]